Locating a real-valued function in a 2-dimensional matrix - computational problem
I need help in understanding conceptually how to solve the problem of locating a chosen function in a 2-dimensional matrix in programming. Let me explain what I mean precisely. I have two 1-dimensional real grids (arrays) of $x(i)$ and $y(j)$, where $i, j = 1, 2, ..., n$. For each combination of those grids, I have a real-valued function $f(x(i),y(j))$ stored in a $n \times n$ matrix. Let's now pick a real-valued function $g(z,w)$, assuming that it lies somewhere in the created matrix at the unknown coordinates $z$ and $w$. Graphically, it will look like this:
  f(x(i),y(j)) - - - f(x(i),y(j+1))
       |                    |
       |       g(z,w)       |
       |                    |
f(x(i+1),y(j)) - - - f(x(i+1),y(j+1))

The question now is, what are the necessary conditions to make sure that the function $g(z,w)$ lies in the presented square? My idea is that the function $g$ should satisfy the following two conditions:

$f(x(i),y(j)) < g(z,w) < f(x(i),y(j+1))$,
$f(x(i),y(j)) < g(z,w) < f(x(i+1),y(j))$,

when  $f(x(i),y(j)) < f(x(i),y(j+1))$ and $f(x(i),y(j)) < f(x(i+1),y(j))$.
Or perhaps it is enough to check if $f(x(i),y(j)) < g(z,w) < f(x(i+1),y(j+1))$, when $f(x(i),y(j)) < f(x(i+1),y(j+1))$.
